# How to configure Elastic Beanstalk nginx proxy for secure websockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my Ruby on Rails (`5.0.1`) application in attempts to support websockets (`ActionCable`) via both insecure (`ws://`) and secure (`wss://`) connections. Failing that, I would be happy with secure-only, but I can only get insecure to work. I have been following [this tutorial](https://anandhub.wordpress.com/); my `.ebextensions/proxy.config` file exactly matches theirs, as do my load balancer settings (`TCP`, `SSL`, etc.).

I can successfully use insecure websockets. I can also successfully connect over both `http` and `https`, so the certificate is good. The *only* thing that does not work is secure websockets (`wss://`):

- `http://api.skill.guide` *works*
- `https://api.skill.guide` *works*
- `ws://api.skill.guide/cable` *works*
- `wss://api.skill.guide/cable` **does not work**

Testing via [this online websocket tester](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html), I see `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404` in the console. Here are the server logs, first showing a successful insecure upgrade, followed by a failed secure upgrade. Note the missing `HTTP_UPGRADE` in the secure senario, leading me to believe there is something wrong with my reverse proxy configuration.

```
[2016-12-17T23:16:41.230931 #9482]  INFO -- : [5d63e807-6df7-4044-af9c-656b25db9065] Started GET "/cable/?encoding=text" for 172.31.26.218 at 2016-12-17 23:16:41 +0000
I, [2016-12-17T23:16:41.252495 #9482]  INFO -- : [5d63e807-6df7-4044-af9c-656b25db9065] Started GET "/cable/?encoding=text" [WebSocket] for 172.31.26.218 at 2016-12-17 23:16:41 +0000
I, [2016-12-17T23:16:41.252578 #9482]  INFO -- : [5d63e807-6df7-4044-af9c-656b25db9065] Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
I, [2016-12-17T23:16:44.643256 #9482]  INFO -- : Finished "/cable/?encoding=text" [WebSocket] for 172.31.26.218 at 2016-12-17 23:16:44 +0000
I, [2016-12-17T23:16:47.786466 #9498]  INFO -- : [3e502e9b-2773-4ab8-8e7e-d6e46b137ac2] Started GET "/cable/?encoding=text" for 73.222.141.98 at 2016-12-17 23:16:47 +0000
I, [2016-12-17T23:16:47.804715 #9498]  INFO -- : [3e502e9b-2773-4ab8-8e7e-d6e46b137ac2] Started GET "/cable/?encoding=text"[non-WebSocket] for 73.222.141.98 at 2016-12-17 23:16:47 +0000
E, [2016-12-17T23:16:47.804789 #9498] ERROR -- : [3e502e9b-2773-4ab8-8e7e-d6e46b137ac2] Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
I, [2016-12-17T23:16:47.804832 #9498]  INFO -- : [3e502e9b-2773-4ab8-8e7e-d6e46b137ac2] Finished "/cable/?encoding=text"[non-WebSocket] for 73.222.141.98 at 2016-12-17 23:16:47 +0000
```

In the interest of completeness, here is my setup.

### Load balancer:

[image]

### `.elasticbeanstalk/proxy.config`:

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream rails {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
        keepalive 256;
      }

      server {
        listen 8080;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://rails;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location /static {
            alias /var/app/current/static;
        }

      }

container_commands:
 removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```

### `config/production.rb`

```
  config.action_cable.url = 'wss://api.skill.guide/cable'
  config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

Comment: The problem is relatively same with Django channels.